# Mosaic to New Raster doesn't actually output anything

Tags: raster, arcmap, mosaic

I am attempting to Mosaic some Raster files together using ArcMaps/Catalog's Mosaic to New Raster tool. It goes through the motions of adding each .tif file we are using, then after a bit it says that is has Succeeded.

If I check the reports and look at where it says it outputs there it has the GDB I specified.

However, when I navigate to the GDB there is nothing there. I have run this a number of times and each time is the same. Nothing appears in any of the GDBs I attempt to send the new Raster Mosaic to.

Anyone run into this?

Comment: Just a little clarity here, is the file being created and is empty? or is the file not there at all?

Comment: File is not there at all. Goes through entire process, says Successfully completed. No file.

Comment: Are you trying to add rasters to a mosaic, or to export a mosaic dataset to a new raster? You're talking about 'adding tif files'.

Comment: A screen shot of how you have set the tool up would be useful.